# X-Frame-Options Header Not Set in nodejs is not working in mozilla & IE salesforce lightning mode

Tags: node.js, header, lighting, x-frame-options

`X-Frame-Options` `Allow-From` is not working in Mozilla & IE browsers for Lightning mode

I have tried below setting in the Apache config file.

```
Header always set X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM https://na112.lightning.force.com/"

Header always set X-Frame-Options "ALLOW-FROM https://smt12.na112.visual.force.com/"
```

It is working for chrome but not working for Mozilla & IE.

Got below error on console when load the App in the salesforce.

> Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://smt12.na112.visual.force.com/ does not permit framing by https://na112.lightning.force.com/one/one.app?source=alohaHeader.

Comment: I'm not too experienced with apache but I believe you need to change `always set` to `append`.